# Field from mysql database as the parameter of function?

Tags: mysql, function, parameters, onclick, imagemap

what is wrong here? The question is in the title? I am a novice in this. Any help is appreciated...

```
<map name="ddd">
 <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="xxx" href="#" onclick="AjaxGet('$row['id']','$row['firstname']','$row['surname']');">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using php here. You would have to refer to your object as follows in html.

```
<map name="ddd">
 <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="xxx" href="#" onclick="AjaxGet('<?php  $row['id']?>','<? $row['firstname'] ?>','<?php $row['surname']?>');">
</map>
```

Also I would recommend the following : Use objects to read your data instead of displaying them on your page directly from the database.

Instead of using onclick use the [jquery click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to do your bindings